# Django inline formset

Tags: django, inline-formset

I have a parent and several child forms using an inline formset. It works fine.

Depending on a value in the parent form, I need to check that the right number of child forms has been submitted.

I know I can access the parent form using self.instance.FOO when overriding BaseInlineFormSet and again this works fine, but I can't find a way to determine how many actual forms have been submitted and vitally have data in them.

Anyone know how?

Many thanks

Comment: Please add some code like your `forms.py` and your view and template so we can better assist you

Answer (score 3):

In the formset `clean` method, `self.cleaned_data` will be a list of dictionaries - one for each form. So you can do:

```
class MyInlineFormSet(formsets.InlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        if len(self.cleaned_data) != self.instance.my_value:
            raise forms.ValidationError('wrong number of forms')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Daniel for pointing me in the right direction. I achieved what I needed by overriding baseinlineformset and doing the following in the clean method:

```
    # submitted form counter
    i = 0

    for form in self.forms:
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        if cleaned_data:
            # discounts forms marked for deletion
            if not self._should_delete_form(form):
                i = i + 1

    if self.instance.ownership.type == 'Joint' and i < 2:
        raise ValidationError(
            "You must enter both clients when specifying joint "
            "ownership."
        )
```

etc.

I also found that I also needed to remove any forms being deleted during the same post from the form count.